# Where can I find Chris Barry's 2013 Apex Developer Training Videos?

Tags: apex, video

Last year, Salesforce [seems to have released videos](http://saramorgan.net/2013/08/12/updated-podcasts-of-apex-training) of Chris Barry's DEV501 level Apex developer training through iTunes.

It sounds like these would be a valuable update to the videos from 2009.  However, they seem to no longer be available through iTunes, and I can't find them on [other sites](http://www.podcast.de/podcast/203774/) either.

Does anyone know if they are available elsewhere ?

Thanks.

Rob

Comment: Did anyone downloaded the videos before it being removed.If so please upload in youtube so that it will be useful to everyone

Answer (score 4):

Why not ask Barry himself on twitter? https://twitter.com/BarryForce

Or you can ask Salesforce University on twitter as well: https://twitter.com/SalesforceU

They should both be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they have removed the training videos.Please find the [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=All&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=90630000000hm9fAAA)